# Change Android app status from Free to Paid during Alpha tests

Tags: android, google-play, publishing, google-play-console

As we almost finished our game, we set up game Google Dev account, to test obb file download and services such as leaderboards. Game is meant to be "Paid". During app setup, we accidentally chose "Free", forgot about that and published it for Alpha tests. It was never live on market, but we still can't change its status from "Free" to "Paid". Is there any solution how to achieve that, different than creating a new app with different package ID?

Answer (score 2):

No, once you set an app to free, it can't be changed back to paid. You can see more information [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/138412):

> Important: If you change an app from Paid to Free and save the change,
>   the change is permanent. Once changed to free, the app can't be
>   changed back to a paid app. If you want to charge again for a paid app
>   that you’ve changed to a free app, you would need to create a new app
>   with a new package name and set a price for the new app.

When you say "It was never live on market", that is a common misconception. Regardless of how you publish it (whether to the public, alpha or beta), you are still publishing the app, just to different audiences. But your app will still be subject to all the rules of the Play Store's terms and conditions as if you were publishing to the public.